# Is there a lok above the lok of lord Vishnu a soul can achieve?

Tags: shiva

We know sarya lok is the highest materialistic lok a soul can achieve. It can also go to the lok of Vishnu lok. Is there lok above that also by which I mean is the lok of lord Shiva the final destination where the souls finally merge with the almighty.